Distorted output waveform when connecting push-pull amplifier to transformer
I'm trying to make a power amplifier to amplify a 200Hz to 5kHz sine wave (2Vpp) from waveform generator to ±150V. The load will not draw more than 600mA, so the amplifier would need to be around 100W. I use two op-amps to amplify the 1 Vpp to 22 Vpp at V aop2 on the schematic. Then I use this signal to drive N and P channel mosfets in a push-pull configuration where the drains are connected to ±25V. I get a good waveform if I connect a 300 Ohm power resistor.

However, when if I connect the output to a transformer (Hammond LR3130 115V primary, 50V, 0.3A secondary) with a 2k resistor, the waveform is distorted. I connected the secondary to the output of the push-pull and the primary to the load to have a step-up transformer.

Why does connecting the transformer to the output mess up the waveform?
How can I steup up my signal without any distorsion?



I suspect the problem is that you are using a tranformer designed for power line frequencies (50-60 Hz) and not audio frequencies. Your screen shots are for a frequency of 2 kHz. How are the waveforms at 200 Hz or lower?

There is no path from transformer to V aop2, how is it becoming distorted?  I cannot determine an answer from here; you will have to do further probing and analysis to determine it. Please edit your post when reporting these findings.

@TimWilliams it could have been more clear in the schematic. I was trying to show both situation but imagine the transformer is connected to the sources of the mosfets

Ah, let me clarify: there is no causal path, from output terminal, to op-amp output terminal, where a change in load voltage, current or impedance, can affect the op-amp's output, say by drawing current through it.  The MOS gates are a capacitance, an open circuit at this frequency, and further isolated with series resistors (RB1-2). If you are telling us V aop2 is distorted when a load is connected, either it was distorted before the load was connected, too, or the circuit is not as indicated. (Might these, in fact, be BJTs, not MOSFETs?)

How much swing does the opamp make? what is the supply volts rating of the opamp?

I think the supply rails are overloaded and collapsed (partially, at least), and this is reflected to the all pre-amp outputs. I don't know what's the total load impedance at ~2 kHz, though.

I suggest focusing on getting the circuit working correctly without the transformer, ie: just the 300Ω load resistor.  Then once that is done and circuit operation is well understood, then start to introduce the transformer later and treat that as a separate project.
To proceed, I suggest make the changes as per the marked-up schematic below, specifically:

Connect the feedback of 2nd op-amp to the output node.
Add resistors into the source of each MOSFET (R10-R15).  Select one value for all these resistors such that at no input signal, the MOSFET idle current causes a voltage drop across these resistors of about 10% of the typical MOSFET gate-source voltage under no-input signal condition.  No need to change these to suit each MOSFET, one value for all six resistors should be adequate.
Add resistors into the gate of each MOSFET (R21-R26). A value of 1KΩ is a good starting point.  This resistor is intended to prevent HF oscillations.
Adjust RB1 and RB2 to get an idle current of about 20mA in each MOSFET (about 10% of the expected peak current contribution of each MOSFET, 600mA / 3 = 200mA, * 10% = 20mA.  That means a standing power loss of about 440mW per MOSFET.
A capacitor across R6 (feedback of 2nd op-amp) may be required for stability reasons.  Start off with 100pF for now.


Concerns:
You may not get the full output voltage swing required of +/-22V from +/-25V supply.  I suggest focus on getting the MOSFETs to share the load current well (that is the purpose of the added source resistors), and then worry about how to reach the peak output voltage after getting a good understanding about how these MOSFETs behave.

Hi Fabio thanks for the tips. The load is a plasma and the current drawn depends on the voltage (https://i.imgur.com/1TqAZYc.png, the number in red is what I would expect). But to see clearly saturation, I will need to get to ±150V. If I use a step up transformer, the current drawn on the mosfets will multiply which is why I intend to split the current in three mosfets later on.



I don't want the current to be drawn from the op-amp so I don't know if it would be ideal to connect the feedback to the output node.


For now, my circuit has 1 mosfet. But because the load will vary, I don't know how I would choose the value. The voltage drop would vary with the load. If it's just to make sure every mosfet shares the same current, it would be easier to not put R10-R15.


I put 1kΩ.


I put R1=R2=8.44kΩ and Rb1=Rb2=1.56kΩ using two 10kΩ potentiometers.


Ok I put 100pF.



Now with Rg=1k, I don't get as much distortion, but I have that the voltage at the load decreases as the load gets lower. (https://i.imgur.com/iuWbrEB.jpeg) I was expecting the voltage amplitude to stay constant but the current would increase.

Hi Jeremy, 1. if your scope is 4 channel, put ch3 on +Vcc and repeat last test (load of 300 ohm).  If your scope is only 2 channel, then move ch1 to +Vcc. 2. How many MOSFETs do you have operating on this test?


What is current in MOSFET with no input signal?  How did you measure this?  4. What value did you use for R10 to R15?  5. Next test: put scope probe on gate of M1, show scope screen showing this with load voltage with load=1k, then 300ohm.



I had 1 mosfet for this test (1x IRF530, 1x IRF9530)
For now, I used LTspice to find the values, but I will need to get a more precise potentiometer if I want to get closer to 30mA. It seems to be very sensitive. According to the simulation, a difference of 50Ω can make the idle current drop to 10mA or make it go up to 110mA.
I didn't put anything for R10-R15 bceause I'm trying with 1 mosfet only and I want to minimize the voltage drop.
Will try tomorrow


Ok. 6. Did you connect the feedback resistor to output node?  Do not be concerned, this does not cause load current to be taken from opamp, quite the contrary in fact, it reduces the opamp output current.

I tried quickly but it had distortion for loads under 3kΩ. I will try more tomorrow

OK.  7. When testing, keep the load resistance fixed, and gradually adjust the amplitude of signal generator V2 (the waveform applied at input to opamp1) from low to higher values.   Look for the output starting to deviate from expected, and report what the voltage at the output of opamp2 is at that point.


Note that 300ohm at 22V will require ~75mA into the load, so you only need 10% (~7mA) of this to be the current at idle, 30mA is too high for this load.  Yes, the idle ("bias") current will be very sensitive to potentiometer setting, that is one of the reasons for R10 to 15, to reduce this sensitivity.  This may need adjustment for the final load (the transformer) but let's not worry about that just yet, there is much to be learned before that.


@moderator  The system is asking to move this discussion to "chat".  However, I suggest leaving this here for the time being, for the reason that, IMO, this discussion is instructive for others.  It provides a real-world example of how a question and a well-intentioned answer can quickly evolve into a detailed conversation, as new information (such as test results from changes to the circuit) is revealed, and new changes are suggested as a result of the new data.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
